# Shutting down VM instances created by dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform

i am having issues with 3 VM instances created via dataflow
I have used a cloud function to launch a dataflow template, which ran to completion
but the VM instances generated for this are still running and i cannot delete them
could anyone help?

thanks and regards

Comment: Do you try to stop your dataflow job? Is it done? Is it in stream or batch mode?

Comment: From the information you provide it is difficult to point out the root of the problem or how to solve it. Can you provide any relevant Stackdriver logs? Perhaps it is useful for you to open a [public issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) where GCP engineers can take a look to this.

Answer (score 1):

so because i kicked off the template via cloud function, GCP didnt allow me to shut down the instance, the options were greyed out. HOwever it was saying that the instances were in use by few GCP groups, so once i deleted the group i was able to delete the instances
the problem seemed to come from my job, wher ei had a wait_until_finish() at the end of my pipeline,w hich was preventing the job from completing
Once i removed wait_until_finish, the job completed and the instances were shut down
thanks and regards
 Marco